# Any rational number $r\ge1$ can be a the k1 density of a simple graph

Tags: graph-theory

Soultion at : [Help with strongly balanced graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4838914/help-with-strongly-balanced-graph)

I will start with some definitions since I was given the following definitions in another language and couldn't find an equivalent in English.

For a graph $G=(V,E)$, $|V|=v, |E|=e$, we will define its density to be $d(G):= \frac ev$ and $m(G)=$$max$ $d(H) , H\subseteq G$. We will say that G is dense if $m(G)=d(G)$, and we will say that G is densest if for any $H\subsetneq G$ $d(H)\lt d(G)$,

we will also define $d_1(G)=\frac e{(v-1)}$, and $m_1(G)=max$ $d_1(H)$ and say that $G$ is $k_1$ densest if for any $H\subseteq G$ such that $H$ has more than one vertices: $d_1(H)\lt d_1(G)$.

Now I am trying to solve the following question:
Let $1\le r \in \Bbb Q$ find a graph $G$ that is $k_1$ densest such that $d_1(G)=r$.

Attempt:

If $r=1$ we will look at the graph with 2 vertices and 1 edge to get $d(G)=\frac 1 2$ hence $d_1(G)=1$ and since any subgraph of $G$ has 1 vertics by defination $G$ is $k_1$ densest.

Else, assume $r>1$:
exist $p,q \in \Bbb N$ such that $r= \frac qp$,we will create a graph $G$ with $n*p+1$ vertices and  $n*q$ edges, $1\lt n\in \Bbb N$, such that the ratio of $\frac {nq}{np+1}$ makes sense for a simple graph, let's remember that in a simple graph with $l$ vertices there are at most $\frac {l(l-1)}2$ edges. $p>q$ since $r>1$ thus $nq>np$ thus $nq \ge np+1$ (since $nq,np$ are natural numbers) so $G$ has more edges than vertices.

By the pigeon-hole principle, any choice of connecting the edges must result in a cycle. we will start by constructing a connected graph with $np+1$ vertices and edges such that the graph has a cycle in it and for the left $nq -(np+1)$ left edges we will add each time to the vertice with the minimal degree till we have no more edges left, we will end up with a graph $G$ such that the minimal degree of $G$ is at least 2, and for any
$H \subsetneq G$ since $v(H)< v(G)$ each vertice that we removed in H also took out at least 2 edges.

Now I think this is the right way to solve the question but yet with my construction I am stuck at trying to solve the inequality of the defination of $k_1$ densest.

Any hint or help would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess that in the definition of a $k_1$ densest graph $H$ should be a *proper* subgraph of $G$.

Comment: If $r=\frac qp>1$ then *$q>p$*.

Comment: @AlexRavsky I have stated all of this, how does it help me?

Comment: @Gidfuck: Alex was pointing out two errors in the question. In the definition of a densest graph, you rightly have $H\subsetneq G$, but in the definition of a $k_1$ densest graph, you have $H\subseteq G$ (which makes no sense since the inequality isn't satisfied for $H=G$). And you wrote $p\gt q$ where you meant $q\gt p$.

Comment: Regarding the terminology: in Alon and Spencer, the term "density" is also used for the same concept, but $\rho(G)$ is the notation used for the density of $G$, and the term for a graph $G$ such that $\rho(G) > \rho(H)$ for every proper subgraph $H$ of $G$ is "strictly balanced". (Similarly, $G$ is "balanced" if $\rho(G) \ge \rho(H)$ for every subgraph $H$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to have minimum vertex degree $2$, if $r > 2$. As an example we can take a graph $G$ isomorphic to $K_5 \cup K_1$ with $2$ extra edges (between vertex of $K_1$ and $2$ vertices of $K_5$). Then $\delta(G) = 2$, $d_1(G) = \frac{12}{5} < \frac{10}{4} = d_1(K_5)$. (This example can't be created by your method, just illustrates my statement.)

On one hand, your method is likely to give minimum degree
$$\lfloor \frac {2nq}{np + 1} \rfloor \ge \frac{2nq - (np + 1) + 1}{np + 1} = \frac{(2nq - np) np}{(np + 1)np} = \frac{n^2pq + np(nq - np - 1) + np}{(np + 1)np} \ge \frac{n^2pq + 2(nq - np - 1) + np}{(np + 1)np} = \frac{nq(np + 1) + nq - np - 2}{(np + 1)np} \ge \frac{nq(np + 1)}{(np + 1)np} = \frac{nq}{np} = r$$
if $np \ge 2$ and $nq \ge np + 2$. (Cases $np = 1$ and $nq = np + 1$ could be considered separately.)

On the other hand, it is not guaranteed that at some moment it will not have all vertices of minimum degree already adjacent. Such an unpleasant case could spoil this lower bound. But the more essential problem is the following. We need to consider all subgraphs, not only those which have one vertex less. And this lower bound about minimum degree can't be inherited by all subgraphs.

Let consider an example which potentially can be created by your method. Let $r = \frac{32}{11}$ and $n = 1$. It starts from cycle $v_0v_1v_2v_3v_4v_5v_6v_7v_8v_9v_{10}v_{11}v_0$ and adds one by one edges
$$v_0v_2, v_1v_4, v_3v_5, v_6v_8, v_7v_{10}, v_9v_{11},$$
$$v_0v_3, v_1v_5, v_2v_4, v_6v_9, v_7v_{11}, v_8v_{10},$$
$$v_0v_4, v_1v_3, v_2v_5, v_6v_{10}, v_7v_9, v_8v_{11},$$
$$v_0v_5, v_6v_{11}.$$
Note that each edge is added between two vertices of minimum degree. Then we have
$$d_1(G) = \frac{32}{11} > d_1(G - \{\,v_i\,\}) \in \{\,\frac{27}{10}, \frac{26}{10}\,\},$$
$$d_1(G) = \frac{32}{11} > d_1(G - \{\,v_i, v_j\,\}) \in \{\,\frac{23}{9}, \frac{22}{9}, \frac{21}{9}, \frac{20}{9}\,\},$$
and so on, until
$$d_1(G) = \frac{32}{11} < \frac{15}{5} = d_1(G(\{\,v_0, v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5\,\})).$$
This example shows that the graph should be regular not only in sense of vertex degrees, but in some deeper sense of global structure.

[To be continued with an alternative solution.]

Comment: Yea I realized that this doesn't work and that this question is above my paygrade lol I have crated a new attempt here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4838914/help-with-strongly-balanced-graph based on a paper I read.... is there a possible chance you can give me some hint to what went wrong there? or an alternative solution here? Thanks!