# Help with strongly balanced graph

Tags: graph-theory

This is a follow up to a post I posted [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834103/any-rational-number-r-ge1-can-be-a-the-k1-density-of-a-simple-graph)

first defintions:

$d_1(G)=\frac{e(G)}{v(G)-1}$

we say that $G$ is $k_1$ balanced iff $d_1(H)\le d_1(G)$ for any $H \subseteq G$

we say that $G$ is $k_1$ strongly balanced iff $d_1(H)<d_1(G)$ for any $H \subsetneq G$

Theorem: There exist a balanced graph with $v$ vertices and $e$ edegs iff $1\le v-1 \le e \le \binom{v}{2}$. According to the following [paper](https://people.clas.ufl.edu/avince/files/StronglyBalanced.pdf) on section 2.

attempt of taking the balanced graph therom and trying to make it strongly balanced.

set $n=v-1$ and $e=kn+r$ where $r$ and $k$ are integers such that $0\le r <n$.

Denote by $C(n,k)$ a graph with the vertex set ${1,2,....,n}$ and edge set ${{x,y}}$ such that $|x-y| \le k-1 (mod n)$, denote by $D(n,k)$ the graph obtained from $C(n,k)$ by joining a new vertex $n+1$ to all vertices of $C(n,k)$.

Let $R(n,r)$ be the following set of points almost equidistriubuted around $C(n,k)$: $R(n,r)$={x| $\lfloor (x-1)r/n \rfloor $ < $\lfloor xr/n \rfloor, 1\le x \le n $, x is an integer}. we will show that exist a strongly balanced graph $G$ such that $G=(v,e)$.

We will have to look at 5 cases:
the 3 trivial cases:

1. k=1 and r=0
2. k=1 and r=1
3. k=1 and r>1

the non trivial cases:

4. k>1 and $n\le 2k$ thus its easy to show that $e\ge \binom{n}{2}$, we will define $G$ to be the graph onbtained from $K_n$ by adding one vertex and $e-\binom{n}{2}$ edges. We will assume the worst possibility that $H$ is a complete proper subgraph of $G$, we will get that $d_1(H)= \frac{\binom{v(H)}{2}}{(V(H)-1)}$ =$\frac {v(H)}{2} \le \frac {v-1}{2} = \frac n 2 \le k \le \frac {kn+r}{n}$, **Here I am having an hard time trying to make the theorm work for a strong inequality** since if r=0 we get eqauility so any help here would be helpful!
5. k>1 and $n \ge 2k+1$ we will define G to be the graph obtained from D(n,k) by adding the r edges {x,x+k},$x \in R(n,r)$ its trivial that those edges are distinct.
   We will define $f$ a function from proper subgraphs of $G$ to proper  subgraphs of $G$ as follows $f(H) = d_1(G)(v(H)-1) - e(H)$, note that if $f(H)>0$ we get that G is $k_1$ strongly balanced.
   Now assume H is a proper subgraph of G and assume that the vertix n+1 $\in V(H)$, let $G_s$=G(v,ns+r) and let $f_s$ be the corresponding deficit function: $f_s(H) = d_1(G_s)(v(H)-1) - e(H)$ for s=2,3...... the paper sates that its easy to show that if $f_s(H)>0$ for any $H$ a proper subgraph of $G_s$ then $f_s+1(H')>0$ for any $H'$ a proper subgraph of $G_{s+1}$ **Here is where I need help again I am having an hard time showing that if $f_s(H)>0$ then $f_s+1(H')>0$...**

any help in cases 4 and 5 would be appreicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that the article has different definition of balanced and strongly balanced graphs:
[image]
[image]
[image]

So what they call *strongly balanced* you call just *balanced*. If you need to have strict inequality, I would recommend introducing a new term like *strictly strongly balanced* or whatever you want.

Case 4 can be subdivided to get a strict inequality.

- If $r = 0$ and $k = \frac{v}{2}$, then $G \cong K_v$ and $d_1(G) = \frac{v}{2} > \frac{u}{2} = d_1(K_u)$ for any $u < v$, i. e., $d_1(G) > d_1(H)$ for any $H \subsetneq G$.
- If $r = 0$ and $k = \frac{v - 1}{2}$ then "steal" one edge from $K_n$ and give one more edge to the vertex $n + 1$. Note that degree of this vertex $n + 1$ is $e - \binom{n}{2} + 1 = \frac{n}{2} + 1 < n$ since $\frac{n}{2} = k \ge 2$. So in this case for $|H| < n$ we have $d_1(H) \le d_1(K_{|H|}) = \frac{|H|}{2} < \frac{n}{2} = d_1(G)$ and for $|H| = n$ we have $d_1(H) < d_1(K_n) = \frac{n}{2} = d_1(G)$.

In the case 5 if $f_s(H) > 0$ for all $H \subsetneq B_s$, then $f_{s + 1}(H) = d_1(B_{s + 1}) (v(H) - 1) - e(H) = \frac{e(B_{s + 1})}{n}(v(H) - 1) - e(H) = \frac{e(B_s) + n}{n}(v(H) - 1) - e(H) = (d_1(B_s) + 1)(v(H) - 1) - e(H) \ge (d_1(B_s) + 1)(v(H') - 1) - (e(H') + v(H') - 1) = d_1(B_s)(v(H') - 1) - e(H') = f_s(H') > 0,$ where $H' = (V(H), E(H) \cap E(B_s))$ and therefore graph $H$ has at most $|H| - 1$ edges missing in the graph $H'$ if $H$ contains universal vertex $n + 1$. Note that if subgraph $H$ doesn't contain the universal vertex then changing any vertex to the universal one decreases $f_s(H)$.

Comment: That has helped me alot, tyvm!

Answer (score 1):

For case 4 you can prove the case $r=0$ separately with $K_\frac{2e}{n}$ because you get $d_1(G)=\frac{e}{n}$ which keeps the wanted ratio (it's not the actual number of vertices and edges but that's not relevant in your question).